# Keras validation loss and metric inconsistent

Tags: validation, keras, recurrent-neural-network, metrics, loss-function

- RNN model used for regression, cf. Chollet, Deep Learning with Python, 6.3.1 A temperature-forecasting problem
- In this example I used random data, both regressors and regressand
- I have used the mean absolute error, both as loss function and as a metric
- I do not understand the values I get for val_loss and val_mean_absolute_error. Neither of them make sense to me.

code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import layers
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import keras
```

I use random input data:

```
data_np = np.random.rand(6400,10)
target_np = np.random.rand(6400,)
```

Normalizing the data:

```
mean1 = data_np[:].mean(axis=0)
std1 = data_np[:].std(axis=0)  
    
data_np -= mean1
data_np /= std1
        
mean2 = target_np.mean(axis=0)
std2 = target_np.std(axis=0)
        
target_np -= mean2
target_np /= std2
```

Create RNN input with lookback:

```
lookback = 7

train_data = np.array([data_np[(i-lookback):i,:] for i in range(lookback,len(data_np))])
target_data = target_np[lookback:len(data_np)]
```

And then set up a simple RNN:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.SimpleRNN(64,
                     activation = 'relu',
                     return_sequences=False,
                     input_shape=(train_data.shape[1], train_data.shape[2])))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))

opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.1)

mae = tensorflow.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()

model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=mae, metrics=[mae])
history = model.fit(train_data, target_data,
                              steps_per_epoch=round(0.7*len(train_data))//64,
                              epochs=10,
                              shuffle=False,
                              validation_split=0.3,
                              validation_steps = round(0.3*len(train_data))//64,
                              verbose=1)
```

The output then looks like this:

> Train on 3495 samples, validate on 1498 samples Epoch 1/10 54/54
> [==============================] - 2s 38ms/step - loss: 0.7955 -
> mean_absolute_error: 0.7955 - val_loss: 0.0428 -
> val_mean_absolute_error: 22.6301 Epoch 2/10 54/54
> [==============================] - 2s 30ms/step - loss: 0.7152 -
> mean_absolute_error: 0.7152 - val_loss: 0.0421 -
> val_mean_absolute_error: 22.2968

I would expect val_loss and val_mean_absolute_error to be the same. Moreover, the levels don't make much sense either. After 10 epochs, I get

> Epoch 10/10 54/54 [==============================] - 2s 32ms/step -
> loss: 0.7747 - mean_absolute_error: 0.7747 - val_loss: 0.0409 -
> val_mean_absolute_error: 21.6337

If I calculate the mean absolute error manually:

```
N=len(data_np)

val_data = np.array([data_np[(i-lookback):i,:] for i in range(round(0.7*N),N)])
val_target = target_np[round(0.7*N):N]

model_output = model.predict(val_data)

model_output=[output[0] for output in model_output]
np.mean(abs(model_output-val_target))
```

> 0.940300949276649

This looks like a result that one could expect. However, it is not even close to either val_loss or val_mean_absolute_error. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

OK. I managed to solve the issue by consistently using tensorflow.keras. So, replacing

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import layers
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import keras
```

with

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow.keras
```

(and corrected a couple of details in the original question)